# how to disable back button in browser when user logout in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I need to disable the back button whenever the user logsout or gets logged in VBScript. Currently when the user clicks it is going back to application again.  I want the user to be directed to login page when he clicks back button or it is fine if I could disable the back button.could anyone help me on this please.

Comment: I voted this question down because the question has nothing to do with Classic ASP/VBScript.

Answer (score 3):

You CANNOT disable the back button of the browser. This is the way the web works, embrace it.

That said, you can expire the pages to prevent the browser from caching them:

```
<%
  Response.Buffer = True
  Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now() - 1
  Response.Expires = 0
  Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
%>
```

Check this article: [A Thorough Examination of "Disabling the Back Button."](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201700/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111500-1.shtml) for more info

Answer (score 0):

It's a dirty trick, but you could include this little javascript in the head of every page:

```
window.history.go(1);
```

Ofcourse, people that have javascript disabled will be able to use the back button just fine.
I agree with Eduardo, it's better to leave the back button functional, it frustrates users if it doesn't work as expected.

The best solution would be to have an include at the top of every page that checks if a user is logged in and if not, redirect to the login page.

You need to check that anyway, because if you don't check on every page it means that people can go to that page without logging in if they know the URL.

Answer (score 0):

you can check session value on top of every page and if session value is blank then redirect to login page, so when user logged out it clear session value then if some one come on that page and do any operation it will not allow to do any operation on that page.